# Filter Ndb query by custom property

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I'm trying to:

1. Add timezone info to `end_date` from `NdbModel`
2. Run Query that compares `end_date` to another `date_with_timezone`, so I fetch only models where `end_date` is before `date_with_timezone`

   ```
   class PageSchedule(NdbModel):
       end_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

       def end(self):
           return self.end_date.replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('US/Central'))
   ```

Then I'm trying to call it from another `Class`

```
schedules = PageSchedule.query(
    PageSchedule.end() < date_with_timezone )
).fetch()
```

But apparently cannot make it work.

```
TypeError: unbound method end() must be called with PageSchedule instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do queries with with properties, not with functions of them.  There is an easy solution, however:

```
schedules = PageSchedule.query(
    PageSchedule.end_date < date_in_UTC )
).fetch()
```